# find facebook useid logged in in otherapp in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new in iPhone app development want user id who is logged in in phone but different app.
I have used Facebook sdk and can fetch user-id from safari but problems come from other applications

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you asking for. Please can you try to reformulate your question (maybe providing an example)?

Comment: assume that we have two app both are using fb sdk
if user is loggen in with app first not from device browser
i want to access user id of that user in app 2nd

Comment: The Facebook SDK doesn't allow you to share the same login session between two different app. If you have a second app the user will need to go through the login process a second time.